# Is it ok to insert ascii decimal characters in postgres select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need o/p of select statement in this way.

You are assigned to following projects:

- A
- B
- C

There are some spaces, special characters & new lines. To do that I used ascii charaters chr(10), chr(32), chr(8226).
It's working fine but query doesn't look good & I am not sure if it's a good approach to do it like this.
The query looks like this

```
SELECT 
'You are assigned to following projects:' || chr(10) || chr(32) || chr(8226) || chr(32) ||
string_agg(e.projects, chr(10) || chr(32) || chr(8226) || chr(32))
```

Also will this work in all OS & in every environment?

Comment: For new line you could use `\n`, for space you could use space, for bullet you could use `•`. So, `\n •` instead of bunch of `chr()`

Comment: I tried it in place of chr(10) but didn't seem to work. If I add it in quotes, it prints '\n' & if I add it without quotes, it gives error

Comment: Well, it does work for me

Comment: How do you use it? I used it like this    string_agg(e.projects, \n || chr(32) || chr(8226) || chr(32)

Comment: I attached a screenshot to my answer

Comment: Why would you do that in a query instead of in the application?

Comment: cz this message can be forwarded or replied  to. So every time it happens I have to make changes for every reply or forward or view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have  a few options:

- Insert characters literally. Usually the best option. Want a "•"? Use a string like `'this is a •'`. Nothing more is required *if* your `client_encoding` is correct and the encoding you're using includes the character you want (like `•`). This is SQL-standard. Newlines may be included as literals:

  ```
  SELECT '
  ' AS "this_is_a_newline";
  ```

  This approach may not work for some non-printable characters, depending on the database implementation. For PostgreSQL it's fine for everything except `\x00`, the zero byte, which PostgreSQL doesn't support in `text` / `varchar` etc at all, only in `bytea`.

  Watch out to make sure your text editor / SQL editor's text encoding matches what your connection tells PostgreSQL the `client_encoding` is, otherwise you'll get mangled strings or weird errors. Users of unix-like terminals also need to make sure the terminal encoding matches `client_encoding` to avoid weird output errors. These days Windows is the only platform where this is generally an issue.
- Insert characters by hex or unicode literal in an `E''` escape-string, e.g. `E'this is a \u2022'` . Note that `\u` escapes are hexadecimal - 0x2022 is decimal 8226. The `E''` syntax is a PostgreSQL extension.
- For characters that have shorthand escapes defined, use the shorthand escapes in an escape-string, e.g. `E'\n'`. This is a PostgreSQL extension.
- use `chr(8226)`, as you described, but note that `chr` interprets the code according to your `server_encoding` (the database's text encoding). So I do *not* encourage it. For multi-byte chars you'll just get an error like `ERROR:  requested character too large for encoding: 8226`:

  ```
    regress=> CREATE DATABASE latin ENCODING 'latin-1' LC_CTYPE 'C' LC_COLLATE 'C' TEMPLATE template0;
    CREATE DATABASE
    regress=> \c latin
    You are now connected to database "latin" as user "craig".
    latin=> SHOW server_encoding;
     server_encoding 
    -----------------
     LATIN1
    (1 row)

    latin=> SHOW client_encoding;
     client_encoding 
    -----------------
     UTF8
    (1 row)
    latin=> select chr(8226);
    ERROR:  requested character too large for encoding: 8226
  ```

  but for chars whose ordinal is in the 1-byte range, you can get an unexpected character instead. Take `ü`, which in both utf-8 and latin-1 (iso-8859-1) is `0xfc` (decimal 252), but in iso-8859-5 is `ќ`. So:

  ```
   regress=> SHOW server_encoding;
   server_encoding 
   -----------------
   UTF8

   regress=> SELECT chr(252);
   chr 
   -----
    ü

   regress=> CREATE DATABASE iso5 ENCODING 'iso-8859-5' LC_CTYPE 'C' LC_COLLATE 'C' TEMPLATE template0;

   regress=> \c iso5

   iso5=> SELECT chr(252);
   chr 
  -----
   ќ
  ```

So my advice: Always use literals where possible. Where you must use escapes, use `E''` strings with unicode escapes to prevent ambiguity about the meaning of a codepoint based on the current server encoding. Avoid `\x` escapes and `chr`.

For the specific example you wrote, you should use:

```
SELECT 'You are assigned to following projects:

    • A
    • B
    • C';
```

---

Note for readers on very old PostgreSQL versions: Extremely old PostgreSQL release didn't support `E''` strings and treated *all* strings as if they were escape strings. So `'\n'` meant "newline" whereras modern PostgreSQL follows the SQL standard in which `'\n'` is just the string "\n". Only marginally prehistoric versions still did this, but raised a warning about it and let you request the standard behaviour by setting `standard_conforming_strings = on`. This has been the default for quite a while.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how to include '\n'. Next line? I am not able to do that.

Comment: Okay. I used it with escape character. E'sfsfsfs \n sdfsfsdf'

Comment: @user1298426 A literal newline works fine. Edited to add demo.

Comment: @user1298426 Also, a warning about how `chr` varies with server encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
chr(10) || chr(32) || chr(8226) || chr(32)
```

just use

```
\n •
```

No reason to use `chr()` in this case.

[image]

Comment: does it depend on postgres version? cz I am not getting next line here. Instead it prints '\n'. My version is 9.3

Comment: You must be on an old version or have `standard_conforming_strings` off.

Comment: Okay. I used it with escape character. E'sfsfsfs \n sdfsfsdf'. Thanks.